# Gstreamer Playbin fails to play video on Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have hard time getting the **playbin** element working on a VM. When I run the pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
```

I get the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'source': gst.soup.session=context, session=(SoupSession)NULL, force=(boolean)false;
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Got context from element 'playsink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstGLImageSinkBin:glimagesinkbin0/GstGLColorConvertElement:glcolorconvertelement0: Failed to convert video buffer
Additional debug info:
gstglcolorconvertelement.c(218): gst_gl_color_convert_element_prepare_output_buffer (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstGLImageSinkBin:glimagesinkbin0/GstGLColorConvertElement:glcolorconvertelement0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Does anyone know why the element **glcolorconvertelement0** fails to convert the video buffer?

I'm currently working on a VM with xubuntu (18.04.1), with the last gstreamer pakage installed (1.14.1).

Additional info: I've got the same error also when I try to play a local .mp4 file. Outside of the VM it all works just fine.

Thanks to you all

Comment: Please adjust your language settings from iatalian to english and post the error code  such that also non-italian speakers can understand the error. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. It's as simple as changing the (virtual) video card on the VM Screen settings.

[VM Screen Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cygK3.png)